# Can buildroot build the device tree for u-boot?

Tags: linux, u-boot, buildroot

I made a custom board and try to use `BR2_EXTERNAL` with buildroot to have a single folder to manage on git. This contains the board defconfig, the scripts for image generation and u-boot/linux defconfig.

I configured my device tree for the kernel in the buildroot defconfig, this is fine, the kernel build it when I run buildroot, but u-boot will not and will complain :

`Device Tree Source (arch/arm/dts/Myboard.dtb) is not correctly specified.`

`Please define 'CONFIG_DEFAULT_DEVICE_TREE'`

`or build with 'DEVICE_TREE=<device_tree>' argument`

in the buildroot menuconfig, I added a custom device tree for the kernel, and a slightly different one for u-boot.

So far, it seems that buildroot will copy the `.dts` in u-boot folder `arch/arm/dts/` but not compile it into a `.dtb`. For that I would need to add my source file to the Makefile in the dts folder.

Is there any option in the `menuconfig` or `uboot-menuconfig` that I am missing ?

Comment: The answer is "yes". The error message (which you provided without any context) confirms that a DT compilation was attempted but failed. Looks like you have a naming and/or path issue; when in doubt specify a full path. And use the correct/expected filename extension (i.e. a *source* file should not have a **.dtb** extension).

Comment: Yes I will edit to add more context but i don't think that compilation was attempted, the dts for uboot is almost the same as the kernel and i can see in the build process that it just could not find the .dtb (since it never compiled it), there are no errors in the log for device tree compilation